# Generate XYZ tiles (MBTiles) from MapTiler QGIS plugin map not showing any labels

Tags: qgis, mbtiles, xyz-tiles, maptiler

I'm fairly new to QGIS, but i already had success generating MBTiles in other projects.
This time my base layer is from the MapTiler plugin (layer name : MapTiler Planet).

I had success doing a print layout and exporting to PDF. Generating MBTile gets me everything except the labels included in the MapTiler layer. Same problem for XYZ (directory), no labels..

I don't know if it is normal since MapTiler is a "commercial freeware" (but the labels were there on the pdf...) or if it is a bug, or me doing something wrong.